# boostrap 3 + datatables buttons: misalignment

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3, datatables

I'm experiencing misalignment when using boostrap 3 and datatables buttons (https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/). How to align them propery?
[image]

everything works fine when on `div.dt-buttons` margin is set `margin-top:2px;`, don't know why, but it feels wrong is there any "standard way"?

```js
$(document).ready(function(myApp) {
  myApp.myDataTable = $('.my-table').DataTable({
    fixedHeader: true,
    paging: true,
    buttons: {
      dom: {
        button: {
          className: ''
        }
      },
      buttons: [{
        extend: 'colvis',
        tag: 'button',
        className: 'btn btn-default'
      }]
    }
  });

}(window.myApp = window.myApp || {}));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.0/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.0/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.0/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css" />

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="dataTables_info" id="DataTables_Table_0_info" role="status" aria-live="polite">Showing 1 to 12 of 24 entries</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <div class="dataTables_paginate paging_simple_numbers" id="DataTables_Table_0_paginate">
      <ul class="pagination">
        <li class="paginate_button previous disabled" id="DataTables_Table_0_previous">
          <a href="#" aria-controls="DataTables_Table_0" data-dt-idx="0" tabindex="0">Previous</a>
        </li>
        <li class="paginate_button active">
          <a href="#" aria-controls="DataTables_Table_0" data-dt-idx="1" tabindex="0">1</a>
        </li>
        <li class="paginate_button ">
          <a href="#" aria-controls="DataTables_Table_0" data-dt-idx="2" tabindex="0">2</a>
        </li>
        <li class="paginate_button next" id="DataTables_Table_0_next">
          <a href="#" aria-controls="DataTables_Table_0" data-dt-idx="3" tabindex="0">Next</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <div class="dt-buttons">
      <button tabindex="0" aria-controls="DataTables_Table_0" type="button" class="buttons-collection buttons-colvis btn btn-default" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    <span>Column visibility</span>
                    <span class="dt-down-arrow">▼</span>
                </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why not upgrade to 5 first?

Comment: I mad you the snippet you could have made for us. The screen has to be wider than the viewport in this page snippet to see the problem but it is recreatable

Comment: In case you did not realize: The snippet (the one which @mplungjan kindly created for you) was a good demonstration of the problem. After you updated the snippet code, it no longer appears to run correctly - there is no output.

Comment: updated code
https://jsfiddle.net/ofuk6mz3/1/

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways you could go here. I'd probably remove the margin from the pagination list as a reset. You can then add spacing back in using your grid instead.

```js
$(document).ready(function(myApp) {
  myApp.myDataTable = $('.my-table').DataTable({
    fixedHeader: true,
    paging: true,
    buttons: {
      dom: {
        button: {
          className: ''
        }
      },
      buttons: [{
        extend: 'colvis',
        tag: 'button',
        className: 'btn btn-default'
      }]
    }
  });

}(window.myApp = window.myApp || {}));
```

```css
ul.pagination {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.0/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.0/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.0/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css" />

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="dataTables_info" id="DataTables_Table_0_info" role="status" aria-live="polite">Showing 1 to 12 of 24 entries</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <div class="dataTables_paginate paging_simple_numbers" id="DataTables_Table_0_paginate">
      <ul class="pagination">
        <li class="paginate_button previous disabled" id="DataTables_Table_0_previous">
          <a href="#" aria-controls="DataTables_Table_0" data-dt-idx="0" tabindex="0">Previous</a>
        </li>
        <li class="paginate_button active">
          <a href="#" aria-controls="DataTables_Table_0" data-dt-idx="1" tabindex="0">1</a>
        </li>
        <li class="paginate_button ">
          <a href="#" aria-controls="DataTables_Table_0" data-dt-idx="2" tabindex="0">2</a>
        </li>
        <li class="paginate_button next" id="DataTables_Table_0_next">
          <a href="#" aria-controls="DataTables_Table_0" data-dt-idx="3" tabindex="0">Next</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <div class="dt-buttons">
      <button tabindex="0" aria-controls="DataTables_Table_0" type="button" class="buttons-collection buttons-colvis btn btn-default" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    <span>Column visibility</span>
                    <span class="dt-down-arrow">▼</span>
                </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```